# Phonegap IOS:webView:didFailLoadWithError - A server with the specified hostname could not be found

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, cordova, inappbrowser

I am integrating facebook and twitter using inAppBrowser in ios phonegap application.It works fine still yesterday evening.But today during login time i am getting the following error in console:

"webView:didFailLoadWithError - A server with the specified hostname could not be found."

How can i fix this problem?Please suggest a solution...

Thanks

Comment: have u added <access origin="*" /> in ur config.xml

Comment: @mvp yes it is already added in config.xml

Comment: not working both twitter and fb login?

Comment: @mvp both login shows same error.

Comment: is this how ur InAppBrowser code looks like?
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('https://.xxxx.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=index.html','_blank','location=no');">Facebook</a>
        <br>

Answer (score 0):

```
You are not showing your code, so not able to see what your authorize url? If thats url not working , you can use following code.
```

connect = function(client_id,redirect_uri,display) 
    this.client_id = client_id;
    this.redirect_uri = redirect_uri;

```
var authorize_url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?";
    authorize_url += "client_id=" + client_id;
    authorize_url += "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri;
    authorize_url += "&display="+ ( display ? display : "touch" );
    authorize_url += "&type=user_agent";

var ref = window.open(authorize_url, 'random_string', 'location=no');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
                     //alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
} );
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    var access_token = event.url.split("access_token=")[1];
    var error_reason = event.url.split("error_reason=")[1];

     if(access_token != undefined){
           access_token = access_token.split("&")[0];               
         setTimeout(function() {
                    ref.close();
                    }, 5000);

     }
     if(error_reason != undefined){

          window.location.href = "error.html";
          setTimeout(function() {
                    ref.close();
                    }, 5000);
     }
        //console.log(event.url); alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);

} );
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
                     //alert(event.type);
} );}
```